# Lint why not allow null to be assigned?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I'm following this [quide](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter) but I've chosen not to disable TSLint default settings. However maybe I should have because right now it's giving me an error message when I try to assign a null (to any type):

```
function f()
{
    const a :string = null; //Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'
    return a;
}

f();
```

It's the same for a number. My question is why TSLint have chosen to completely disable such constructs. Additionally is it ok if I instead assign an empty string like this instead:

```
    const a :string = "";
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not a TSLint error - it results from your `tsconfig.json` file having the `strictNullChecks` setting enabled. This makes `null` an invalid value for all types that do not explictly state they can be null.

Here's an example of how the behavior differs ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20a%3A%20string%20%3D%20null%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20fails%20with%20strictNullChecks%0D%0Alet%20b%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%20%3D%20null%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20does%20not)):

```
let a: string = null;         // This fails with strictNullChecks
let b: string | null = null;  // This does not
```

This means that if you have the setting disabled, every `Type` is actually being treated as if it were `Type | null | undefined` under the hood!

So, why might you want to turn a feature like this on? It seems fairly inconvienent at first glance, but the benefit is in how it allows you to catch null pointer errors at compile time instead of at runtime.

Consider the following function ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20parseCSV(input%3A%20string)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20input.split(%22%2C%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AparseCSV(null)%3B)):

```
function parseCSV(input: string): string[] {
    return input.split(","); // If input is null, this will error!
}
```

With `strictNullChecks` disabled, you can call `parseCSV(null)` and you'll not get an error until you actually run the code. With it enabled, passing in null will cause a compile error!

In an ideal world (at least in my opinion!), this would be the default, but because so much existing JavaScript code throws around nulls/undefined with reckless abandon, it was decided that the setting should be opt in for compatibility's sake. If this behavior is not desirable for you for whatever reason, then you can change that setting to `false` or remove it from the config file to revert to the default.

Comment: Any more explanation why I would want that setting - would be appreciated since I'm a new to this typescript thing.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions: Extended my answer a bit.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions: Just added a more practical example of why you might want to enable that setting - hope it helps :)